# Developing pages to take care browser compatibility

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser

What are the things to take care, when developing asp.net pages to support browser compatibility?

What I mean is, layout is not properly shown in all browser as required, but working well in some browser. I think this is the major issue to every one to achieve browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout doesnt need to look exactly the same in every browser, but it needs to degrade gracefully in order to expose the core functionality.

What I have learned developing layouts for different browsers is that, the less hacks you use, the better.

This should in theory, be increasinly easy to do, with the demise of IE6.

a short list would include:

- reset the css
- use a js framework that's tested
  against the majority of browsers
- dont use css hacks
- validate your html
- make your web developers work closely
  with your web designers, or have 1
  person be both.
- test against the browsers you want to
  be compatible with
- know your browsers streghts and
  weakneses

virtual machines are your friends for cross browser testing, or stand alone (portable) apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule that would work in all situations. Each case is unique.

What is important is to develop pages that validate. Before a page validates, any complaints about browser issues cannot be taken seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Start your site for Firefox and IE and then test with Chrome. Do not use any code which is dependent on any one browser.
Ensuring your site works across all browser is not easy. There are multiple browsers and then there are smart phones which should display your content gracefully.